# Cypher delete a node and all related nodes if they don't have a further relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To keep my database clean from orphaned nodes, I want to delete a Node - identified by a given property value - and every related Node **that does not have** any other related nodes.

Is that possible? Currently I'm doing this:

```
MATCH (poi:PointOfInterest)-[r]-(allRelatedNodes) 
WHERE poi.id="X007" 
DETACH DELETE poi, r, allRelatedNodes;
```

But that deletes all related Nodes *including the ones that would be connected to other Nodes* if they weren't deleted.

Is there a way to delete a Node and all related Nodes that don't have relations to other Nodes?

---

**Edit by the author**:

The marked answer is correct. I finally solved my problem with

```
MATCH (poi:Node)-[r*0..1]-(allRelatedNodes) 
WHERE poi.name = "A"
AND size((allRelatedNodes)--()) < 2    
DETACH DELETE poi, allRelatedNodes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the `allRelatedNodes` match optional and ensure `allRelatedNodes` only have a single relationship to `poi` then you should be able to delete only the ones attached to **X007** if they exist. Also, you don't need to specify `r` in the delete statement as `DETACH` takes care of that.

```
MATCH (poi:PointOfInterest)
WHERE poi.id = "X0007"
WITH poi
OPTIONAL MATCH (poi)-[r]-(allRelatedNodes)
WHERE size((allRelatedNodes)--()) = 1    
DETACH DELETE poi, allRelatedNodes
```

Using Neo4j 3.0 and starting with the following graph...

[image: Starting Sample Graph]

And executing a close facsimile of the above query (listed below)...

```
MATCH (poi:Node)-[r]-(allRelatedNodes) 
WHERE poi.name = "A"
AND size((allRelatedNodes)--()) = 1    
DETACH DELETE poi, allRelatedNodes
```

I am left with this graph.

[image]

If that does not delete it all in one query you could use this instead and that should definitely take care of it.

```
MATCH (poi:PointOfInterest)-[r]-(allRelatedNodes) 
WHERE poi.id = "X007"
AND size((allRelatedNodes)--()) = 1
WITH poi, collect(allRelatedNodes) as allRelatedNodes
DETACH DELETE poi
WITH allRelatedNodes
UNWIND allRelatedNodes as node
DELETE node
```

Comment: This is almost what I want.

Comment: But, this will not delete `poi` in the case when there are other nodes related to `allRelatedNodes`. I need to delete `poi` in any case!

Comment: Any ideas @Dave Bennett?

Comment: hmm thought that would have done the trick.  Do you have a small sample data set that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Bennet my current solution is to execute `MATCH (poi:PointOfInterest) WHERE poi.id="X007" DETACH DELETE poi;` right after your cypher query suggestion. That will delete the `poi`. In combination the two of them do what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Interesting, I just tested it out on the latest download of 3.0 and it deletes both the POI node and the nodes attached to POI that are not attached to anything else. I added the example to my answer above so you can see exactly what I did.

Comment: @matthias I added an alternate solution that i think might work for you since the first one does not

Comment: Doing some more invstigation I must confess that your first proposed solution works (my bad). In my testing scenarios where it did not work, I think that was because of the direction of the relationships. In scenarios, where the direction is set up like in your example, your query works fine (which suffices for my use cases). **Note:** As an example for when it not works, try your query on deleting "A3". As I assume, then, A3 would not be deleted.

Comment: @Matthias - i updated the answer with what i think gets you where you want.  the reason it did not work the way you expected was the first match statement. you need to always match the POI whether or not there are related nodes to delete.  Your query and the the first solution always made a match between the **poi** and the **all related nodes**.  In the case where there are no related nodes (with a single relationship back to the poi) you still want to delete the poi. This query will accomplish that.

Comment: With your help I could solve my problems. Your answer is correct, but I had to change it to `MATCH (poi:Node)-[r*0..1]-(allRelatedNodes) 
WHERE poi.name = "A"
AND size((allRelatedNodes)--()) < 2    
DETACH DELETE poi, allRelatedNodes` to match Pois without further relationships, too. I'll edit my question to include your answer!